# Turn a character string into a formula object in base R

Tags: r, regex, string, formula, lm

I was wondering if there might be a way to turn a character string like `"time"` into a `formula` object like `time ~ 1` in **BASE R**?

***Note:*** By `formula`, I mean as used in `lm()`.

Here is what I tried without success:

```
a = "time"

formula(bquote(.(noquote(a)))~1)

# Desired output a formula object:

time ~ 1
```

Comment: @caldwellst, I saw that but that doesn't help! Could you please try that in `lm`. I want to use that formula in regression! Please note `lm` in my tags!

Comment: If you use `lm` and the formula generated from `formula` or `reformulate`, you'll notice the results of your model will say `formula = f` (if `f` was your formula). If you want your results to show the actual formula, and not the variable that stores the formula, you can do something like this: `model <- eval(bquote(lm(.(f), data = dataset)))` where `f` is the formula, and `dataset` is your data. Thought I would mention in case might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reformulate`

```
a <- "time"
reformulate("1", a)
## time ~ 1
```

This also works:

```
formula(paste(a, "~ 1"))
## time ~ 1
```

### lm

Note that `lm` can take a character string instead of a formula so we don't actually have to convert the string to a formula (except that a formula has an environment attached to it so in some cases it may make a difference although often it won't). Below `ch` could have been pasted together from pieces.  Both of the `lm` examples below work but in the first it will show literally `Call: lm(formula = ch, data = BOD)` in the output whereas the latter will show the actual formula `Call: lm(formula = "demand ~ Time", data = BOD)` in the output.

```
ch <- "demand ~ Time"

lm(ch, BOD)
do.call("lm", list(ch, quote(BOD)))
```